# how to get how many with average age from a state

Tags: sql

So I am going to make a view with: 
- State 
- Average age of people from a state 
- How many with same age as average age of the state

```
create view myView
as
select state, avg(age), count((select avg(age) from person))
from person
group by state;
```

I have tried this, but I only get how many people who are from the state.
Anyone know how I can make it possible?

Answer (score 1):

use subquery

```
create view myView
as select state,avage,count(*) from 
(select state, avg(age) as avage
from person
group by state
) t group by state,avage
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a window function:

```
create view myView as
    select state, avg_age,
           sum(case when age = avg_age then 1 else 0 end) as num_avg_age
    from (select p.*, avg(age) over (partition by state) as avg_age
          from person
         ) p
    group by state;
```

Note that `age` would typically be an integer.  If your database calculates an average of integers as a decimal number, then the count may always be zero.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join your query to the table `person` and group to count:

```
select g.state, g.averageage, count(p.id) counter from (
  select 
    state, 
    avg(age) averageage
  from person
  group by state
) g left join person p
on p.state = g.state and p.age = g.averageage 
group by g.state, g.averageage
```

`id` is the primary key of the table `person`.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9kcc3TLvcUyiJhHQd45GcM/0)

Answer (score 0):

Another way. Basically the same as @forpas's solution, but with a `CTE` instead of a sub-query.

Isolate the average age by state in one data set, then join that back to your base table to get the count of people with matching ages.

```
CREATE VIEW myView
AS

WITH avgAge AS
(
  SELECT 
    state
    ,AVG(age) AS avgAge
  FROM
    person
  GROUP BY 
    state
)
SELECT
  a.state
  a.avgAge,
  COUNT(p.age) AS cntOfAvg
FROM
  person AS p
JOIN 
  avgAge as a
    ON
      a.avgAge = p.age
      AND
      a.state = p.state;
```